# How to create logrotate in linux

Tags: linux, codeigniter, logrotate, log-rotation

How to create new log rotate files for my codeigniter application in LAMP server command line . I want to run this daily process

log files will be like this

```
application/logs/log-2013-06-12.php
application/logs/log-2013-06-13.php
application/logs/log-2013-06-14.php
application/logs/log-2013-06-15.php
```

**here is my log rotate script if any errors please let me know**

```
/var/www/my-app/application/logs/*.php{
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty   
    create 640 root password
    sharedscripts
    dateext
    dateformat -web01-%Y-%m-%d-%s
    postrotate
        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null       
    endscript
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi; \
    endscript
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The config file you created is fine.
Logrotate utility just provides the checking mechanism.

There is `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` file which invokes the logrotate daily.

For testing purpose you can add your cron minutely rule and putting the logrotate's config file 
under that rule.